# Linux sort combining -V and -f

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, gnu-coreutils

I want to combine sort -V and -f.  Is there a way?

Here is simple example.  I want to sort this list.

```
> cat testme

a1
a2
a11
a12
a3
A8
B8
b1
b11
```

Default sort is upper case first, lower case second,  plus a11 comes before a2

```
> cat testme | sort

A8
B8
a1
a11
a12
a2
a3
b1
b11
```

I use -V which is awesome, a2 is before a11, but its still upper case then lower case

```
> cat testme | sort -V

A8
B8
a1
a2
a3
a11
a12
b1
b11
```

I can sort -f which fixes case, but a11 is still before a2

```
>cat testme | sort -f

a1
a11
a12
a2
a3
A8
b1
b11
B8
```

I try and combine them but -V wins and -f loses.

```
>cat testme | sort -f -V

A8
B8
a1
a2
a3
a11
a12
b1
b11
```

Is there an option to combine these?

Desired output is:

```
a1
a2
a3
A8
a11
a12
b1
B8
b11
```

Version in use:

```
[03:11:09] sa-hq1:~ # sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.4
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Is it important that lower case come before upper case? ASCII standard puts upper case before lower case.  If you want to override that standard you might have to resort writing a Perl script and use its sort functionality. Also why "cat testme | sort ...", just do "sort -V testme".

Comment: You only imply the desired output, maybe make it explicit, too?

Comment: Or to be explicit ... *What is your desired output? Please [add it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46230827/edit) to your question.* Also, what distro are you using, and what is the output of `sort --version`? That will help us understand your results and options.

Answer (score 0):

On my Fedora 25, it works properly.

```
    [root@localhost ~]# sort --version
    sort (GNU coreutils) 8.25
    Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

    Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
    [root@localhost ~]# sort -Vf testme
    a1
    a2
    a3
    A8
    a11
    a12
    b1
    B8
    b11

[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: You edited the question and added the `gnu-coreutils` tag. This helps match your answer to the question, but how do you know that this is what the OP is using? While it's *likely*, it's not guaranteed simply because he's using Linux.

Comment: Thanks Nehal for the update.

The desire out is as you show,   sorted by alpha ignoring case and sorted by end number...  your shown output is exactly what I want.

Strangely my sort version is higher.

[03:11:09] sa-hq1:~ # sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.4
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.

Comment: @ghoti sort utility is part of gnu-coreutils and OP has clearly mentioned in the question that he is using sort utility.

Comment: At the time you added the tag, the OP had not added his version information. Please don't assume that everyone uses the same system and tools that you use. Sort is a [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/sort.html) utility, and in lots of places, not just gnu-coreutils.

Comment: Aye aye captain @ghoti , point noted. On a serious note, gnu-coreutils are widely distributed across many linux distros and OP had added linux tag right from the start. Shouldn't tag cover all possibly applicable options ? Nonetheless,thank you for enlightening me on possibility of having sort distributed without gnu-coreutils.

Comment: Thanks guys.   All the Linux hosts I can acess are Centos 6.7 to 6.9 that all have sort 8.4 on them.

I think this is my issue...  I need a higher version of sort.

Answer (score 0):

You **no need** to `cat` file to `sort` command. It can read a file from `stdin` or from `argument list`:

```
sort -Vf file
```

**or**

```
sort -Vf < file
```

**test:**

```
~ > sort -Vf < file

a1
a2
a3
A8
a11
a12
b1
B8
b11
~ > sort -Vf file

a1
a2
a3
A8
a11
a12
b1
B8
b11
~ >
```